# How to calculate the cell a point belongs to on an infinite grid/plane?

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's say I have an infinite plane (in a computer game), on which I lay a virtual grid of quadratic grid cells. Each cell has a side length of `len`. The center of that plane - and thus as well as of the grid - is at coordinates `X=0, Y=0`. Since the plane is "infinite" in size (or at least very large), the grid spans from its center point into all four directions, both positive and negative values on `X` and `Y`.

Now I got a random point on the plane, given as coordinates `px, py`. I want to calculate the grid cell this point belongs to. A cell is defined as its `center` point, as well as its `bounds` (which would be `center + len / 2` in all four directions I guess).

What would be an elegant way to calculate both the cell's `center` and `bounds`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the bounds for a rectangle you only need two points where each point represents opposing corners. You can think of one point as the min x and min y values while the other is represents max x and max y values.

#### Finding the grid cell index

To know which grid cell we are in we can use

```
index_x = math.floor(px / len);
index_y = math.floor(py / len);
```

#### Bounding box from index

If we want to find the points on the original coordinate plane that describe the grid cell at `(index_x, index_y)` we can do this:

```
min_x = index_x * len;
min_y = index_y * len;
max_x = min_x + len;
max_y = min_y + len;
```

#### The modulo way

A more elegant version of this uses the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to calculate the remainder of the coordinate when divided by the length of the grid cells. We can get the minimum coordinate by removing the remainder from the coordinate.

```
min_x = px - (px % len);
min_y = py - (py % len);
```

#### Finding the center

If you want the center point for the bounding box you can do the following:

```
center_x = min_x + len / 2;
center_y = min_y + len / 2;
```

This relies on the fact that the box has edges of length `len`. Thus the center point is one half the length from the minimum x and y positions.

#### A warning

If you are programming this into a computer beware of [floating point error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) as it can cause some unexpected behaviors. As nice as the modulo approach is, it is going to be more prone to floating point error than `math.floor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bounds_x_min = math.floor(px / len);
bounds_x_max = bounds_x_min + 1;
center_x = average(bounds_x_min, bounds_x_max);
```

The `y` versions follow the same pattern.